# the feature of method Promise.prototype.chain in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, documentation, promise, chain

a method in chrome browser named Promise.prototype.chain.
I cannot find any documentation about this method.
Anybody know anything about it?

btw can i find the documentations of google chrome for all methods in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Now `.chain` is just a deprecated alias for `then`.

---

What `chain` does is basically what `then` does except not unwrapping promises. Chain is a proper "monadic flatMap" rather than `then` which automatically unwraps promises.

It was discussed [at great lengths](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/promise-cast-and-promise-resolve) on the mailing list and in TC meetings. It was decided against.

`.chain` is just a relic of the past in Chrome, it *might* make it in a future release but currently no one is championing a proposal including it. I would not use it in production.

Comment: What does "not unwrapping promises" mean and when would you want to use `.chain()` instead of `.then()`?

Comment: @jfriend00 Try `Promise.resolve(3).chain(x => ({then: f => f(4) }) ).chain(c => console.log("Got", c))` vs `Promise.resolve(3).then(x => ({then: f => f(4) }) ).then(c => console.log("Got", c))` - it does not automatically unwrap the result.

Comment: If you wanted to return a promise by itself that was not managed as part of the current chain, you could also just embed it into an object and return that object, right?  Perhaps since I'm so used to how it works now with `.then()`, I can't think of a situation where I'd want `.chain()` logic and, even if I could, I could just hide the promise in another returned object and still use `.then()`.  Are there any other reasons for `.chain()`?

Comment: Right, you could embed it into an object and return the object. There are some motivating example in the esdiscuss thread I linked to in the answer.